# Visual Studio 2012 Server Explorer DefaultView view error?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

Can anyone tell me what the $#%& this is? I'm assuming its a local only issue since I can't find anything on the net pertaining to it in particular.

I've even gone through and **deleted all the Data Connections in the Server Explorer** and I still keep getting this dialogue over and over. It's a fresh install of VS 2012, any insight appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically we had some folder redirection sync issues backing up appdata and basically had to take off the permissions and kill the profile before signing back in.

In other words if you happen to run into this in my scenario of config'ing a new machine while still trying to work on the original and you're logging in as the same user and your appdata is syncing, your paths may not match. Problem solved, but took some figuring to realize the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an icon on top right corner in VS prompting that authentication expired.  I had to re-enter authentication to a Microsoft account in my case a Hotmail account.